# Find minimal number of colors for tables with colored chairs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

We have $s$ tables, $s$ teams, carrying names $1,...,s$, with $s-1$ members in each team. Any table has $s-1$ differently colored chairs. The tables are placed in order $1$ to $s$ and table $s'$ contains a member of each teams except for team $s'$.
Two members of a team, which are by defintion seated at two different tables, are not allowed to sit on identically colored chairs.
How many colors do you need at least to color all chairs in a way which satisfies the previous conditions?

Obviously, this is linked to coloring of graphs. Calling the graph, which we need to color, by $G$ the members of one team form a clique in $G$ of size $s-1$. Additionally, all members seated at one table can be seen as a clique of size $s-1$ and they all need to be colored differently. The remaining pairs of chairs do not have any relationships which constrain the colors.
I do not see how I can go on from this. Does anyone know the minimal number of colors which I need to use for the coloring? And how do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need $s-1$ colours. If you make a $s\times s$ grid of cells, the rows representing the tables, and the columns the teams, then you need all the cells to be coloured so that no row or column has two cells of the same colour. The cells on the diagonal remain uncoloured (or can be considered to share some unique extra colour). This is essentially a [latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) where the main diagonal is of one colour/value.

The simplest latin square gives each broken diagonal one colour, and this leads to a simple arithmetical way to describe the colour assignment:

> On table $p$ the person from team $q$ should take the seat of colour $(p-q) \bmod s$, which is a number from $1$ to $s-1$ inclusive.